# Meaning of “faire souffler le chaud et le froid”

Tags: sens, expressions

> La thermothérapie, vous connaissez? C’est faire souffler le chaud et le froid pour le bien du malade.

What does “faire souffler le chaud et le froid pour le bien du malade” mean?

Answer (score 3):

It is a play on words based on the idiom *[souffler le chaud et le froid](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/souffler_le_chaud_et_le_froid)*: [to blow hot and cold](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blow+hot+and+cold).

Here, it is used literally, i.e. this therapy is using a combination of heat therapy and cryotherapy to treat patients.

*Pour le bien du malade* means "for the patient's sake", "for the sake of the patient's health".

Comment: I wouldn't include  "for the well being"; well being: general health and happines; the idiomatism "for the sake" is acceptable but lacks in a certain specificity particular to English; possibly, "for the sake of the patient's health" might appear preferable. @jlliagre

Comment: @user168676 "Well being" removed. Is "for the good of the patient" usable here ?

Comment: It's more or less equivalent to "for the sake of the patient", which can by the way be formulated a little more concisely as "for the patient's sake".

Comment: @user168676 Thanks, answer updated with your suggestions.